# javascript push associative array in another

Tags: javascript, arrays, associations

I have two associative arrays and want to push one completely to the other.

my current code:

```
LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i].STOCK_DOCCAT = stock_data.STOCK_DOCCAT;
LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i].STOCK_DOCNO  = stock_data.STOCK_DOCNO;
LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i].STOCK_ITMNO  = stock_data.STOCK_ITMNO;
```

im looking for something like this:

```
LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i].push(stock_data);
```

Comment: I dint get your question but you have to do like this if you are pushing **LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data.push(stock_data);**

Answer (score 2):

`.push` is for adding items to an array. You do have an object , and to copy multiple properties into an object,you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign( 
 /*to:*/ LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i],
 /*from:*/ stock_data
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i] = stock_data`.

Note that the previous content (if it exists) of `LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i]` will be **replaced** by a reference to `stock_data`. Any changes made in `stock_data` will be done in `LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i]` If you want a copy, you can use : `LT_WORK_PACKAGE.data[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(stock_data))`